# SnapSVG - parse toDefs() is not a function

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I, im trying to embed font references into the  section of the svg using snapsvg. Heres my snippet

```
this.importFonts = function() {
    var fonts = [
        {
            name : 'Oswald',
            family : 'Oswald',
            url : 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'
        }
    ];
    fonts.forEach(function(font){
        var snapFont = Snap.parse('<style type="text/css">@import url(' + font.url + ');</style>');
        canvas.append(snapFont);
        snapFont.toDefs();
    });
};
```

the style tag is being appended to the svg but I am getting an error

`Uncaught TypeError: snapFont.toDefs is not a function`

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here.

regards

Comment: Ok, console logging the `snapFont` reveals the answer kind of. How do I convert the fragment into a snapsvg element?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, selecting the element through snapsvg will return a snapelement:

```
this.importFonts = function() {
    var fonts = [
        {
            name : 'Oswald',
            family : 'Oswald',
            url : 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'
        }
    ];
    var fontGroup = canvas.g();
    fonts.forEach(function(font){
        var snapFont = Snap.parse('<style type="text/css">@import url(' + font.url + ');</style>');
        fontGroup.add(snapFont);
    });
    fontGroup.selectAll('style').forEach(function(elm){
        elm.toDefs();
    });
    fontGroup.remove();
};
```